# Is there a programmatic way to access a list of all "sets" in a model?

Tags: django

I have three models

```
class Risk(models.Model):
   notes = models.TextField()
   ...

class Component(models.Model):
   risk = models.ManyToManyField(Risk)
   ...

class ReportComponent(models.Model):
   risk = models.ManyToManyField(Risk)
   ...
```

And right now I'm doing the following:

```
def parent_component(self):
    print(self.component_set.all())
    print(self.reportcomponent_set.all())
```

Is there a way to dynamically inspect all the available `..._set` properties?

Comment: As in collections that end with `_set`, or just all related collections? Note that if you have a `ManyToManyField`, then that means that there is also a (hidden) model in between.

Comment: The idea is that in the future, say that I add a new model with another ManyToMany risk field to it, I want to be able to auto discover this. @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: @Stupid.Fat.at, so only `ManyToManyField`s? No `ForeignKey`/`OneToOneField` or its reverse?

Comment: No foreignkey/onetoone field, only ManyToMany, the Risk model would never have manytomany fields to the Components model so I believe it is accurate to say reverse relationship map, yeah? @WillemVanOnsem

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain a list of all fields with `self._meta.get_fields()`. Then you can start filtering these fields. We can then handle these by checking if for that field `f`, the `f.many_to_many` property holds. We can furthermore use the `f.get_accessor_name()` to obtain the accessor.

```
def parent_component(self):
    for f in self._meta.get_fields():
        if f.many_to_many:
            print(getattr(self, f.get_accessor_name()).all())
```